# Как ограничить вывод из Json?

Tags: php, json

Получаю информацию из json

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) {

    if ( $response{$i}["myprice"]["currency"] == 'RUR' ) {

print $response{$i}["myprice"]["total"] .'<br />';
print $response{$i}["title"] .'<br />';

    }

}
```

Если в ответе меньше 10 позиций, получаю ошибку

**Notice: Undefined offset: 10 in**

Как выводить только существующее кол-во позиций но не более заданного?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

для таких ситуаций в PHP есть цикл `foreach()`

```
foreach($response as $item){
    print $item["myprice"]["total"] .'<br />';
    print $item["title"] .'<br />';
}
```

**UPDATE:**

чтоб вывести первые 10 из 20 записей:

```
foreach($response as $key=>$item){

    if($key==10){ break; }

    print $item["myprice"]["total"] .'<br />';
    print $item["title"] .'<br />';
}
```

чтоб вывести последние 10 из 20 записей:

```
foreach($response as $key=>$item){

    if($key<10){ continue; }

    print $item["myprice"]["total"] .'<br />';
    print $item["title"] .'<br />';
}
```

чтоб вывести 10 из 30 записей после десятой:

```
foreach($response as $key=>$item){

    if($key<10){ continue; }
    if($key==20){ break; }

    print $item["myprice"]["total"] .'<br />';
    print $item["title"] .'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как ограничить вывод в вашем примере?

Comment: он уже ограничен. `foreach()` автоматически прерывается после выполнения последней итерации  (сделать это вручную: `if(!isset($item['title'])){ break; }`).

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Спасибо! Просто я имел ввиду, если допустим есть 20, а вывести нужно 10.

Comment: for чем вас не устроил $i <= 10